# Grep and regex on a file with bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep

in a file how could I select line where there is :

`Value_1` and `Name_species`

I should get for instance:

```
Value_1:(O)_content_:Name_species
```

I tried

```
grep "Value_1:*:Name_species" file
```

but it does not work...

Comment: You have to add a dot `.` before the asterix like `.*` or else you are repeating the colon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative

```
grep -E "Value_1:.*:Name_species" <filename>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way to combine two greps is by grepping the one after the other:

```
grep "Value_1" <filename> | grep "Name_species"
```